# Media Query issue in Samsung Edge 6

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am creating a responsive website with bootstrap but for some element
i uses @media Query code below it's working fine in all device.
but

not working in Samsung Galaxy Edge 6 and 7 (360px) **Not any effected** by this query

this is my code what's wrong with it ?

```
@media (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 360px)  {
.glyphicon {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #f05181;
    left: -190px !important;
    padding: 10px 10px 1px 10px;
    top: -75px !important;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this case will never happen because there is no space in between those 2 width.

```
@media (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 360px)
```

when you use media query you need a width difference i.e. (10px):

```
@media (max-width:350px) and (max-width: 360px)
```

or use predefined bootstrap variables like

> @screen-xs

for a max-width of 480px.